# VirtualBox: Share a folder between Mac Host and Windows8 Guest

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, shared

I have a Mac with Virtual Box, on which I'm running Windows 8.
I have set up a Shared Folder in the Virtual Box settings. When I boot up Windows8 through Virtual Box, I can see the Mac as one of the options - screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOijp.png (WINDOWSMAC is the name of the VM. MACINTOSH I'm guessing would then be the host).

I am thinking I need to access MACINTOSH to get to the shared folder. The problem is - when I click on MACINTOSH I am presented with a popup to enter my username and password: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6B00.png

Is this a username password to my Mac Host or to the Windows Guest? It seems neither will work.

Am I missing some step in creating/accessing the shared folder? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think the shared folders live under \\vboxsrv

Comment: Thanks @paulm - it's strange that directory doesn't come up for me... Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the [VM guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). Mount your guest and click the menu item *Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image*. Now you can install it on your guest. Possibly you have to reboot your guest.

Afterwards your shared folder should live under `\\vboxsrv`.

Comment: so that if the folder path on your mac host is `/Users/yourMacUserName`, the folder share name is `mac`, the you could access all your mac files for this user from the `\\vboxsrv\mac` on your Windows guest ...

Answer (score 1):

you share files or folder between host and guest system in a simple way:from the devices menu, chose drag and droop ,the default selection is disabled, other option available are either drag and drop in on direction host-> guest or vice versa or in both direction